# How to find the standard deviation from the given information and what is $B(0)$ equal to?

Tags: brownian-motion, finance, standard-deviation

Assume that the risk free rate is $0$ and that the stock price is given by the equation $S(t)=6e^{2t+2B(t)}$ where $B(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion. Determine the price at time $0$ of the European call option with strike $K=6e^{18}$ and expiration $9$.

The formula I have is $C_E(0)=S\Phi(d_+)-Ke^{-rt}\Phi(d_-)$

where $d_+=\frac{ln\frac{S(0)}{K}+\Big(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\Big)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$ and $d_-=\frac{ln\frac{S(0)}{K}+\Big(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\Big)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$

There are two things I don't understand:
1. The solution uses $\sigma=2$, how do you find the standard deviation from the information given in the question?
2. I need to find $S(0)$ so I plug in $0$ for $t$ in $S(t)=6e^{2t+2B(t)}$ and I get $S(t)=6e^{2B(0)}$, I know $B(0)$ is a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $0$ but does that mean that $B(0)=0$? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, in the Black-Scholes model, the stock price process $\{S(t), t \geq 0\}$ is modelled as
$$S(t) = S(0) e^{\displaystyle \left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t + \sigma W(t)}.$$
Now, comparing the above with $S(t) = 6e^{-2t+2W(t)}$ (note that I wrote $-2t$ instead of $2t$, otherwise it does not hold, so I assume it is a typo) and given that $r=0$, you immediately obtain
$$\begin{cases} 
S(0) = 6, \\
\sigma = 2.
\end{cases}$$
Note that $W(0) = 0$ by definition (in fact, to be precise you should write 'almost sure equal to zero'). You might recall that a standard Brownian motion always starts at zero.

Comment: I understand why $W(0)=0$, but does it even make sense to ask what $W(2)$ equals because this is just a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2$. Asking what is the probability of $W(2) /gt /frac12$ would make sense correct?

Comment: Yes. In general $W(t) \sim N(0,t)$. In particular, $W(0)$ is a r.v with zero mean and zero variance which implies that $W(0)$ can only take the value $0$ (with probability one). To be correct, it should be $\mathbb{P}(W_0 = 0) = 1$.

Comment: I got a similar question to this on my final exam, the stock price given by $S(t)=8e^{4t+4B(t)}$, during the exam I asked my professor if it was a typo because it didn't make sense with the formula $S(t)=S(0)e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+ \sigma W(t)}$ and he told me the equation is correct, so I used $S_t=S_0e^{\mu t+\sigma B(t)}$ to get $\sigma=4$.

Comment: I asked a new question here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800902/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-formulas-that-price-a-stock