# What is the difference between these two formulas that price a stock?

Tags: brownian-motion, finance

What is the difference between these two formulas?
They are both related to the price of a stock in the black-scholes model. The fact that the second one uses $t$ as a subscript which means it's not a function of $t$ (in this case time), but I don't understand what each formula is used for.

$$S(t)=S(0)e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+ \sigma W(t)}$$

$$S_t=S_0e^{\mu t+\sigma B(t)}$$

Comment: could you add some more context?

Comment: $S(t)\equiv S_t$, it's just a different notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Black-Scholes model the stock price process $\{S(t), t \geq 0\}$ is modelled as 
$$S(t) = S(0)e^{\mu t+ \sigma W(t)}, \qquad (*)$$
where $\mu$ is the return on the stock and $\sigma$ the volatility. In a market absent of arbitrage, any discounted price is a martingale. In particular, the discounted stock price is a martingale, that is by definition
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-rT} S(t)] = S(0).$$
To proceed, substitute $(*)$ into the above equation and solve for $\mu$. You'll find $\mu = r-\sigma^2/2$. Hence, for this choice of $\mu$ there is no arbitrage, which is a necessary assumption to price options.